# the different usage of Health and Healthy

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, differences, british-english

.......care has provided us with amenities

a)health

b)healthy

I am a bit confused but I think that we should use (healthy) because it is an adjective for (care) and thus a verb can can be brought after them. also, (health care) as whole is used to describe something, so a name must come after it. 
What is the correct answer supposed to be?

Comment: "Health care" is a noun adjunct (or qualifiying noun) phrase. We don't say "healthy care" ro refer to the care of someone's health.

Comment: oh thanks got your point, but when do we use "healthy care" then?

Comment: We don't normally say "healthy care." When would care be unhealthy? If it was, it would not be "care".